# How offensive is it to call someone a "slag" in British English? (NSFW)

Tags: british-english, slang, offensive-language

One more colorful slang term I gleaned from the British movie I recently watched is *slag*.  In the movie, it was used in curses like, "Fuck-ing dogs! Slags." "Right slag, that one."

Now I know via dictionaries that *slag* means "a loose, promiscuous woman."   But there are multiple slang terms for such a woman in American English that have varying levels of vulgarity -- here's how I would rank a couple of them, from least to greatest in vulgarity:

> **skank** < **slut** < **ho** < **bitch** < **cunt**

So where does *slag* fit on this spectrum?  Of course, I imagine you'd never hear it on proper television, but is *slag* barely elided over when someone goofs and says it, kind of how the word *bitch* is in American English?  Or is it a word that a rough group of friends might use around each other casually, sort of how the word *motherfucker* is in American English, and apparently *cunt* is in British English? Or perhaps *slag* is a word that one should prepare for a fight over if one uses it, like *cunt* in American English?

Comment: Can't say about the Dextropondians but here in 'Merica, "bitch" is not *nearly* as bad as the others.  If one of my daughters said my wife was acting like a bitch, well, I wouldn't be thrilled, but they'd be in serious, serious trouble if they had used a word like "skank".  Partly, it's just that "bitch" means nothing worse than "ill-tempered woman", while the other words have very strong sexual connotations.

Comment: An actual Bitch - a canine, not a human - displays a couple of behaviors, especially when in heat. One is being "ill tempered" - snapping and snarling at her would be suitors - another is being relatively indiscriminate and not exclusive about her sex partners. When we humans apply the word to one of our own species, we may intend to imply either both or only a single one of these behaviors. Hopefully it's clear from the context what's intended, and most of the time a daughter would be complaining only about ill temper. "Slut" as a comparative  example, refers  exclusively to sexual behavior.

Comment: @Malvolio: I disagree about your ordering. 'Bitch' is considered a swear word, not terribly taboo. but still taboo. 'Skank' is not a taboo word. The concept may be distasteful, and calling someone a skank may be as hurtful as call them a bitch, but the word itself doesn't have the stigma value that bitch does.

Comment: @Mitch -- yes, `bitch` does have a slight taboo quality (as a noun; as a verb, meaning "complain", it's harmless), but the underlying sentiments order differently.

Comment: @Malvolio: I can accept t (especially since I was going that direction anyea, that there's a difference between the intensity of the utterance and intensity of the underlying meaning).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Before getting to the main answer, a few points that may be interesting to you (though I realise they're not actually part of your question!):

1. In the UK - at least in some circles, the word *cunt* is an insulting word for a *man*, never a woman: neither I nor those that I've asked have ever heard it used that way, though as the comments below attest, this usage does exist.
2. Of the others, the odd-one-out to me would seem to be *bitch*: I'm not sure about US usage of that word, but to me the others all have a connotation (to a greater or lesser extent) of sexual impropriety. In the UK at least, *bitch* doesn't have that association - it means something along the lines of *woman with an unkind, evil or spiteful personality*.
3. The words *skank* and *ho* are recognised - especially from rap music - but are definitely felt to be American imports. All of the others are fully accepted as native :)

On to the main question: it's probably worth distinguishing between the degrees of offensiveness of (abusing terminology slightly) *use* and *mention* of the words: that is, some words can be happily used in polite society, but one would be highly offended to be *called* one - whereas with some words merely *saying* the word (regardless of who it is applied to) is offensive in of itself.

Having drawn that distinction: *mention* of the word *slag* - while it's clearly to be avoided when on one's best behaviour - is unlikely to cause much offence; that would put it on a roughly similar level to *slut* or perhaps *skank*.

However, *using* the word *slag* to describe someone would be a good way to start a fight. It is probably at a similar level to *slut*: perhaps slightly more offensive, if only because *slutty/sluttish* can refer to general demeanour (in dress, speech) - and indeed can occasionally merely mean ["untidy, slovenly"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slut) with no sexual connotation - whereas *slag* is unambiguously referring to sexual behaviour.

It's worth mentioning the word is used a lot in comedy - perhaps the earliest was in the comic [Viz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fat_Slags) (decidedly *not* a comic for children, and never noted for its reverence); here's an example in [Harry Enfield](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oyUXhXMT3wQ)'s sketch show; and more recently in [Gavin and Stacey](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AVSWAAOaBP8). (Using the word for men isn't common *except* in reference to this show!). You can probably see - especially from this last example - that this word *can* be thrown around among close friends in a humorous way - but I would strongly advise against doing so unless you're very sure of what you're doing, since the line between banter and offence is a very narrow one at times :)

Comment: cunt can be directed towards women in the UK, but it is considered far far worse than calling a man a cunt.  I've only heard it used that way a handful of times and it always provokes an extreme response.

Comment: @Robb: Interesting... those I've spoken to said they'd consider it an error... that said, if someone did use it towards *anyone*, there's no doubt that they're intending to be offensive!

Comment: #1 is definitely wrong, I'm British too and I've seen 'cunt' used to refer to a woman many times. Like Robb said, it's generally considered much worse than saying it to a man.

Comment: I guess it's interesting to note how subjective these things can be. To my ears, 'slag' sounds far, far harsher than 'slut', but less so than 'cunt'.

Comment: @victoriah: It may well be a regional (or social) thing then... I'll edit accordingly!

Comment: @victoriah: And, if 'cunt' is used as a woman - would you say it has a specifically sexual meaning (like 'slag'), or that it's merely generally offensive (like 'cunt' applied to a man)?

Comment: I think it's fair to say that most usage of the word *cunt* is man-on-man.  IME women are offended just to hear the word, let alone have it directed at them.

Comment: I used to live in South London, and I often heard women calling referring to a man's partner / girlfriend as his "bitch". There was no negative connotation. Lower socio-economic circles give a different weight to such curses.

Comment: @trideceth12: In AmE, *a bitch*, when referring to a person (usually female), is offensive but doesn't have sexual connotations, just gender specific (a parallel to *assshole* for a male). Possessively, *his bitch* really does have the sexual connotation (that sex is involved). And more with no stigma attached, just *bitch* really is used by dog breeders for a female breeding dog.

Comment: Remember that *bitch* can also be used as a verb, e.g. "he/she [usually she] was bitching about so-and-so", in which case it's pretty low on the profanity scale!

Comment: @Mitch arsehole isn't specificially male in BrE.  The usual BrE male equivalent to bitch would be *bastard*

Answer (score 6):

It sounds pretty confrontational and insulting, and is certainly disparaging, if not downright offensive.

Etymology [here](http://www.businessballs.com/clichesorigins.htm):

> **slag** - loose woman or treacherous man - the common association is with slag meaning the dross which separates during the metal ore (typically iron) smelting process. In fact the iron smelting connection is probably more of a reinforcing influence rather than an originating root of the expression. Francis Grose's Vulgar Tongue 1785 dictionary of Buckish Slang and Pickpocket Eloquence has the entry: "Slag - A slack-mettled fellow, not ready to resent an affront." In other words a coward. In this sense 'slack-mettled' meant weak-willed - combining slack meaning lazy, slow or lax, from Old English *slaec*, found in Beowulf, 725AD, from ancient Indo-European *slegos*, meaning loose; and mettle meaning courage or disposition, being an early alternative spelling of metal from around 1500-1700, used metaphorically to mean the character or emotional substance of a person, as the word mettle continues to do today. Partridge says that the modern slag insulting meaning is a corruption and shortening of slack-mettled. Certainly the associations between slack, loose, lazy, cheating, untrustworthy, etc., are logical. The mettle part coincidentally relates to the metal smelting theory, although far earlier than recent 20th century English usage, in which the word slag derives from clear German etymology via words including *slagge*, *schlacke*, *schlacken*, all meaning metal ore waste, (and which relate to the coal-dust waste word slack), in turn from Old High German *slahan*, meaning to strike and to slay, which referred to the hammering and forging when separating the waste fragments from the metal. Slag was recorded meaning a cowardly or treacherous or villainous man first in the late 18th century; Grose's entry proves it was in common use in 1785. Slag meaning a female prostitute seems to have first developed much later - around the 1950s - and its more general application to loose girls or women is later still, 1960s probably at soonest. So the notion that slag came directly from the iron and steel industry to the loose woman meaning is rather an over-simplification. The first slags were men, when the meaning was weak-willed and untrustworthy, and it is this meaning and heritage that initially underpinned the word's transfer to the fairer sex.

Comment: I first encountered "slag" about two weeks ago on another board and its use engendered (heh) quite a controversy. While there may have been an obsolete use of the term (ex 'slack-mettled'), I suspect this resurgence is disassociated from prior etymology.

Comment: So the word's alleged UK origin 'slack-mettled' is similar to the US slang term 'slacker'. Interesting.

Answer (score 4):

As a British woman, I would say the answer depends entirely on context and intent. But if the intent is cruelty, then slag and slut are pretty much equal, but slut needs a little more caution (see below). Both mean loose and dirty. Bitch and cunt (here) mean something else, they don't mean loose, they mean spiteful, cruel, nasty.

But, as I say, it depends on context.

Many women here are trying to reclaim cunt as a powerful word for their genitalia, and fair play to them. But at the moment, cunt is not a word you would risk using in any society, let alone a polite one.

Also, here, we (men especially) quite often refer to each other as slags in a very humorous way by extending the 'a', as in, 'You slaaaaag'. And it just means to suggest someone's being a bit cheeky or naughty. And in that context, especially if you're a bit of a lad, it's almost a compliment!

If one of my girlfriends had a one-night-stand or even snogged some guy in a club, I could quite easily call her a slag and she wouldn't be offended, because of the lack of intent. I wouldn't, however, call her a slut. It doesn't have the same humorous connotation.

HTH

Comment: Can I offer "slattern" into the mix, please?  And its adjective, "slatternly". According to Cambridge Dictionary: a dirty, untidy woman, (US slang disapproving) a woman who has many sexual partners, for pleasure or payment. Slatternly eg: "He lived in a slatternly apartment with two other graduate students."

Comment: Curiously, _slut_ used to have the same meaning (dirty and untidy) - I've even seen it in an early 20th century children's book in that sense!

Answer (score 3):

Slag is probably between *bitch* and *cunt* on your spectrum. It's **not** a word someone would use casually. You would only use it to describe someone that you really dislike and even then other words are to be preferred.

If you directly refer to someone as a slag then yes, you should prepare for a fight. My mental image of a situation where ''slag'' is used involves two groups of chavvy women, drunk, outside a pub, late at night, fighting over someone's boyfriend. That's pretty much the only time you should use the term.